# Synchronizing object takes too long

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Im currently doing an animation.

One object in my scene has 1million polygons and highres textures.

Just synchronizing the object, during rendering  takes 30 sek.
So with 240 frames, each test-render of the entire animation, takes at least 2 hours.

Without the heavy poly-object it just takes 3 sek per frame.

Why does Blender need to synchronize the entire scene, for each frame of an aniamtion. And can't just do it once ?
Especially when certain objects don't move.

And is there a way to do this just once ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a low poly mesh resembling the high poly mesh, intersect both, bake them and apply the obtained texture to the low poly mesh.

Comment: Hey thanks:) But this doesnt help since the highres texture, make up most of the synchronizing time.  Already tested this. It also doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I think it's happening because of your subsurf modifier value being high, I was messing around in blender and the performance dropped significantly, the culprit was subsurf modifier. If you've already applied that then Shrinkwrap modifier is your best bet. Follow the same procedure that I said in the parent comment, instead of baking them, set shrinkwrap modifier on the low poly then target the high poly.